# Directive that checks validation in AgualrJS - $scope is not defined error

Tags: angularjs

When I trying to do server-side validation on my "name"-field, by adding a directive:

```
 app.directive('uniqueName', function($http) {
    var toId;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
 
            scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(value) {

                    $http.get('/rest/isUerExist/' + value).success(function(data) {

                        //set the validity of the field
                        $scope.$apply(function(s) {
                            ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueName', data);
                        });
                    });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Why it returns **"$scope is not defined"** message in console??

**UPDATE:**

If I use"scope." but not "$scope.", then I have different error in the console:

> Error: $digest already in progress

Answer (score 2):

You've injected it as scope, not $scope. Just change it to `scope.$apply`

Comment: Then it says: Error: $digest already in progress. I guess it is related to asynchronous stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. About my second question:

From doc:

> $apply() is used to enter Angular execution context from JavaScript
>
> Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has
>   already been called for you by the directive which is handling the
>   event.

So, it makes me think that I do not need: `$scope.$apply(function(s) {`

Then my code looks like this (and works as expected):

```
$http.get('/rest/isUerExist/' + value).success(function(data) {

   //set the validity of the field
   if (data == "true") {
       ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueName', false);
   } else if (data == "false") {
       ctrl.$setValidity('uniqueName', true);
   }
});
```